# how to do onclick hide and show in angular different components using service.ts?

Tags: typescript, angular8

In my project, I have a two components like content and view. I am using service.ts for connecting (extend) these two components. in content component I have a method. when I call that method one div will show in view component. both are interacting using service.ts. I tried boolean method but it's not working.

content component:

```
<button (click)="filterService.filterClicked()"
    [class.active]="filterService.filterChanged"
    id="filterDropdown" type="button"
    class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-clear-default job-filter">
    Filter Test</button>
```

content component ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterService } from './filter-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
 name = 'Angular';
 constructor(
   public filterService: FilterService) {

 }}
```

service.ts:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {
  public filterShow: boolean = false
  constructor() {
  }
private _source = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)
show$ = this._source.asObservable()
filterClicked() {
    this.filterShow = !this.filterShow;
    this._source.next(this.filterShow)
}}
```

view component:

```
 <h3 *ngIf="filterService.show$ | async">Show data</h3>
```

view component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterService } from "./filter-service";
@Component({
  selector: 'jobs-sub-header',
  templateUrl: './sub-header.component.html'
})
export class SubHeaderComponent {

constructor(
   public filterService: FilterService) {}
}
```

when I click the filterClicked() in content component, in view component the content should show and hide. but it's not working for me.. I don't know where I missed anything?

Comment: try debugging by subscribing in your constructor to see if the value actually updates

filterService.show$.subscribe(r => console.log(r));

Comment: actually i used this in content component, there its working fine -<h3 *ngIf="filterService.show$ | async">Show data</h3>

Comment: @Roj it showing false but not updating when i click again.

Comment: then there's a problem with he way you're updating your value. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If its showing false then there is a problem with the way you're updating your value. try passing a value to **next()** instead of the one declared in your service

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {
  constructor() {
  }

private _source = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)
show$ = this._source.asObservable()
filterClicked(value) {
  this._source.next(value)
}}
```

then just create a toggle function in the content component that needs to be clicked on

```
show: boolean;
subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private FilterService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.FilterService.subscribe(r => this.show = r)
}

toggle() {
  this.FilterService.filterClicked(!this.show)
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

and then replace the click function in your content component

```
<button (click)="toggle()"
[class.active]="show"
id="filterDropdown" type="button"
class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-clear-default job-filter">
Filter Test</button>
```

Comment: generally it's a bad idea to initialize data in your service and mutate them at the same time. You should initialize them outside the service on the components that is using it and then only use the BehaviorSubject for updating and tracking the state..

Comment: toggle function i have to add content component or view component? because i have a method in content component. but toggle function should happen in view compoent.

Comment: @sankar on the content component. the one with the button being clicked. <button (click)="toggle"
>
    Filter Test</button>

Comment: @sankar can you share in a codesandbox? so I can take a better look at it. or stackblitz

Comment: this is url- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvwcz8?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html i tried same thing in my project but its not working. in stackblitz its working fine.

Comment: @sankar made some changes. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpydk7?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: thanks for your efforts. but unfortunately that also not working. i dont know where i have the problem.